# Appwarp fails to re-connect after user disconnects from the server (using cocos2d-x)

Tags: cocos2d-x, multiplayer, appwarp

I am trying to work through connection issues at this stage of the app writing process.  When the user leaves the game board, I call ...

```
void HelloWorld::onExit()
{
    isMultiPlayer = CCUserDefault::sharedUserDefault()->getBoolForKey("MULTIPLAYER", false);
    if(isMultiPlayer)
    {
        AppWarp::Client::getInstance()->disconnect();

        CCUserDefault::sharedUserDefault()->setBoolForKey("MULTIPLAYER", false);
    }

    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->removeDelegate(this);
    CCLayer::onExit();
}
```

From here, if I try to re-join the lobby, I get a

```
onConnectDone .. FAILED with unknown reason..session=0
```

Error in my log file.  It seems like I need to wait around 5 minutes or so before this error disappears.  Am I doing something wrong with my disconnect code, or is this kind of behavior the norm?

Comment: This seems like a bug in the SDK where some state is not being cleaned up for a period of time. I work on the AppWarp team. I think you should be able to reconnect within a minute. We will be releasing a bug fix SDK update later this week. I will post an answer once that is done. Thanks for reporting this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PWiggin - this issue has now been fixed in our SDK update. You can pick the latest release from our GIT repo. Here is the link
https://github.com/shephertz/AppWarpCocos2DX/tree/master/V_1.5.1

Comment: I'll go ahead and mark this as an answer, but I am still having some issues.  Best to contact customer support directly?

Comment: We've also just launched our own community forum! We'll be quite active there so you can post your questions there. Here is the link - http://forum.shephertz.com